# Problems with random numbers (C)

Tags: c, random

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int x;
    int y[100];
    int b0 = 0, A0[100];

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (x = 0; x < 100; x ++)
    {
        y[x] = (rand()% 1000)+ 1;
    }
    int ans;

    for (x = 0; x < 100; x ++)
    {
        ans = y[x] % 10;

        if(x == 0)
        {
            printf("Frist group(Last for'0')\n");
        }
        if (ans == 0)
        {
            A0[b0] = y[x];
            b0++;
        }
    }

for (i = 0; i < b0; i ++)
{
    for (j = b0; j > i; j --)
    {
        if (A0[j - 1] > A0[j])
        {
            A0[j - 1] = A0[j - 1] ^ A0[j];
            A0[j] = A0[j - 1] ^ A0[j];
            A0[j - 1] = A0[j - 1] ^ A0[j];
        }
    }
}

    for (int count0 = 0; count0 <= b0; count0 ++)
    {
        printf(" %d  ", A0[count0]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

here is my output.

```
Frist group(Last for'0')
 32766   1000   840   630   900   500   830   520   80   470   510   760
```

I don't know why when I run this program every time, the frist number is always a strange integer.

Can any one please help me, I want to know what is casuing this problem.

(I had forgot to upload the sort part of my codes.)

Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use `malloc` and `free` for the `A0` and `y` arrays, valgrind on Linux provides the following output:

```
Frist group(Last for'0')
==9169== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9169==    at 0x108972: main (foobar.c:40)
==9169== 
==9169== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9169==    at 0x4E8737A: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==9169==    by 0x4E8EAA5: printf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==9169==    by 0x108A24: main (foobar.c:51)
==9169== 
==9169== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==9169==    at 0x4E8329B: _itoa_word (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==9169==    by 0x4E86A0F: vfprintf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==9169==    by 0x4E8EAA5: printf (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==9169==    by 0x108A24: main (foobar.c:51)
```

Notice the last line in each section: inside your `main` function at line 40, there is an "uninitialised value". This means your program is trying to read a value from an address where you never stored/wrote a value. That's the `if (A0[j - 1] > A0[j])` line. Since it's an array access, the problem is with the value `j` used in the loop.

You typed `b0++` after writing to `A0[b0]`, so if `b0` is 0 when you do `A0[0]`, then `b0++` makes it 1. In other words, you have:

- `b0==1`: `A0[0]`
- `b0==2`: `A0[0]`, `A0[1]`
- `b0==3`: `A0[0]`, `A0[1]`, `A0[2]`
- ...

This means you only wrote values from 0 to `b0 - 1` when the first loop that assigns values to `A0` is finished. As a result, `j = b0` means you're using `A0[b0]`, which has no value written to it. You're swapping a random number that you assigned at `A0[b0 - 1]` with an unknown number that you never assigned at `A0[b0]`. Because you never assigned it, `A0[b0]` is "uninitialised".

The same issue with `b0` occurs with `count0 <= b0` in your print loop, which is why line 51 is also shown to be a problem. Change it to `count0 < b0`, and all issues with the array access of `A0` are resolved.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

`A0[j - 1]` is outside the array bounds on at least one occasion.

Also, your print loop stopping conditional needs to be `count0 < b0` rather than `count0 <= b0`.

Everything else looks fine.

Comment: I find out that when i erase the +1 from (rand()% 1000)+1, The stange integer will turn into 0.

Comment: Frist group(Last for'0')
0  310  360  560  580  830  880

Second group(Last for'1')
0  61  91  111  361  471  511  531  551  711  841  911  921

Comment: @KutengF What happens when you use the suggestion? In what way is it wrong?

Comment: @Chrone Kitsune Thanks for helping. Sorry, I think had forgot to upload the sort part of my codes.This "for (i = 0; i < b0; i ++)
{
    for (j = b0; j > i; j --)
    {
        if (A0[j - 1] > A0[j])
        {
            A0[j - 1] = A0[j - 1] ^ A0[j];
            A0[j] = A0[j - 1] ^ A0[j];
            A0[j - 1] = A0[j - 1] ^ A0[j];
        }
    }
}"  would this be the thing that cause the problem?(this part is right after the separate part)

Answer (score 2):

First integer from `A0` cannot be strange, but the last one can be, because you are reading data out of range - condition in loop should be `for (int count0 = 0; count0 < b0; count0 ++)`.

Comment: I disagree that `A0` cannot be strange. That's a manifestation of UB, and is quite rational (insofar that UB can be rational) given that the standard output is typically buffered.

Comment: Thanks for helping :), but i've tried it. This isn't the cause of this problem. But when i erase the +1 from (rand()% 1000)+1 the strange integer will be gone but lefting a 0 in it's place.

Comment: like this  
Frist group(Last for'0') 0 310 360 560 580 830 880 Second group(Last for'1') 0 61 91 111 361 471 511 531 551 711 841 911 921